# Weak and normwise convergence of sequence of linear functionals

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Is this sequence of linear functionals weakly (normwise) convergent : $$f_n((x_j))=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{x_k}{k}} , (x_j) \in \ell_1\,?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the functionals converge in norm.

Hint: $$\left|\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{x_k}{k}\right| \le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|$$